# How to correctly use functions inside loops in CoffeeScript 2?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, coffeescript, closures

#### 1. Summary

I can’t find, what is the correct way to use functions inside loops (or what to replace it with) in CoffeeScript 2 in 2024.

Should I use one of the variations I’ve given below, or CoffeeScript has a better solution?

#### 2. MCVE

I need to run a function inside a loop. The [**global function `setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) in my MCVE solely for example to make the MCVE simple. In real projects I use other functions.

Example array:

```coffee
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]
```

I want to get this console output:

```
Kira is Goddess!
Kira is Ideal!
Kira is Perfection!
```

#### 3. Not helped

##### 3.1. “for…of” loop

```coffee
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

for kiraСharacteristic from kiraСharacteristicsArray

    setTimeout (->
        console.log "Kira is #{kiraСharacteristic}!"
    ), 0
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```js
var kiraСharacteristicsArray, kiraСharacteristic;

kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"];

for (kiraСharacteristic of kiraСharacteristicsArray) {
  setTimeout((function() {
    return console.log(`Kira is ${kiraСharacteristic}!`);
  }), 0);
}
```

Result:

```
Kira is Perfection!
Kira is Perfection!
Kira is Perfection!
```

[**Simple ECMAScript solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/5951529) doesn’t work in CoffeeScript:

1. [**CoffeeScript haven’t `const` and `let`**](https://coffeescript.org/#unsupported-let-const).
2. Unfortunately, [**CoffeeScript compiles solely to `var`, not to `const` and `let`**](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/5377).
3. I haven’t found an [**ESLint plugin**](https://github.com/dustinspecker/awesome-eslint) or any other tool that would correctly replace `var` with `const` and `let` in JavaScript files.

##### 3.2. Closure

As @Alex Wayne described in [**his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220419/5951529):

```coffee
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

for kiraСharacteristic from kiraСharacteristicsArray

    do(kiraСharacteristic) ->

        setTimeout (->
            console.log "Kira is #{kiraСharacteristic}!"
        ), 0
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```js
var kiraСharacteristicsArray, kiraСharacteristic;

kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"];

for (kiraСharacteristic of kiraСharacteristicsArray) {
  (function(kiraСharacteristic) {
    return setTimeout((function() {
      return console.log(`Kira is ${kiraСharacteristic}!`);
    }), 0);
  })(kiraСharacteristic);
}
```

I get expected console output, but ESLint return [**`no-shadow` error**](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow):

> 6:13  error  'kiraСharacteristic' is already declared in the upper scope on line 1 column 16  no-shadow

##### 3.3. “forEach()” method

```coffee
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

kiraСharacteristicsArray.forEach (kiraСharacteristic) ->

    setTimeout (->
        console.log "Kira #{kiraСharacteristic}!"
    ), 0
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```js
var kiraСharacteristicsArray;

kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"];

kiraСharacteristicsArray.forEach(function(kiraСharacteristic) {
  return setTimeout((function() {
    return console.log(`Kira ${kiraСharacteristic}!`);
  }), 0);
});
```

I get expected console output, but [**Unicorn**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn) return [**`no-array-for-each` error**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-array-for-each.md):

> 5:11  error  Use `for…of` instead of `.forEach(…)`              unicorn/no-array-for-each

##### 3.4. “continue” statement

I fixed JavaScript above use ESLint, Unicorn and [**`prefer-arrow-function` plugin**](https://github.com/JamieMason/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow-functions) use `eslint --fix` CLI command:

```js
var kiraСharacteristicsArray;

kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"];

for (const kiraСharacteristic of kiraСharacteristicsArray) {
   setTimeout((() => console.log(`Kira ${kiraСharacteristic}!`)), 0); continue;
}
```

I get expected console output, but ESLint return [**`no-continue` error**](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-continue):

> 6:64  error  Unexpected use of continue statement  no-continue

#### 4. Don’t offer

Please, don’t offer:

1. “Use JavaScirpt, CoffeeScript is bad”.
2. “Don’t use functions inside loops. Read JSHint’s warning”. Yes, JSHint return `warning W083`, when I use a function inside loop:

   > jshint: warning W083 - Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (console)

   But it seems to me that [**`loopfunc` JSHint’s option**](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#loopfunc) is obsolete and doesn’t take into account the ECMAScript features `const` and `let`.
3. “Use Civet instead of CoffeeScript” Yes, I know that Civet [**supports `const` and `let`**](https://github.com/DanielXMoore/Civet/blob/main/notes/Comparison-to-CoffeeScript.md#things-added-that-coffeescript-didnt), see my [**MCVE written on Civet**](https://civet.dev/playground?code=a2lyYdChaGFyYWN0ZXJpc3RpY3NBcnJheSA9IFsiR29kZGVzcyIsICJJZGVhbCIsICJQZXJmZWN0aW9uIl0KCmZvciBjb25zdCBraXJh0KFoYXJhY3RlcmlzdGljIG9mIGtpcmHQoWhhcmFjdGVyaXN0aWNzQXJyYXkKCglzZXRUaW1lb3V0ICgtPgoJCWNvbnNvbGUubG9nIGBLaXJhIGlzICR7a2lyYdChaGFyYWN0ZXJpc3RpY30hYAoJKSwgMAo%3D). But my question about CoffeeScript.

Comment: Can you use one of the options that work, and silence the linter [just for that line]?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is `kiraCharacteristic` being closed over (as you are doubtless aware). If you don't let it get into the closure, you're fine. For clarity, it is not "using functions in a loop" that is a problem; it is *creating* functions in a loop using function literals, because that is what makes a closure.

`setTimeout` is able to pass arguments to its callback; since the arguments passed this way are outside of the callback, they are not closed over.

```
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

for kiraСharacteristic from kiraСharacteristicsArray

    setTimeout ((innerKiraСharacteristic) ->
        console.log "Kira is #{innerKiraСharacteristic}!"
    ), 0, kiraСharacteristic
```

If you are not using `setTimeout`, you should make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that corresponds to your use case. But the root of the problem will still be the closure, if your problem is even remotely similar to what you presented. In this case, you can use `bind` instead, to attach the loop variable's value to the function without it being closed over:

```
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

for kiraСharacteristic from kiraСharacteristicsArray

    setTimeout ((innerKiraСharacteristic) ->
        console.log "Kira is #{innerKiraСharacteristic}!"
    ).bind(null, kiraСharacteristic), 0
```

Now, this is not a particularly CoffeeScript answer, as neither `setTimeout` nor `bind` are CoffeeScript-specific, but it is written in pure CoffeeScript. Whether there is a better way in CS2, I can't say.

Answer (score -2):

```coffee
kiraСharacteristicsArray = ["Goddess", "Ideal", "Perfection"]

`for(const kiraСharacteristic of kiraСharacteristicsArray)
    setTimeout(() =>
        console.log("Kira is " + kiraСharacteristic)
    ), 0)
`
```